# Generate different sentences by dropping inner words

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am going to generate different sentences by dropping words. I think it might be a well-known problem but I can not find it.

as an example: 
if I have a sentence like this **"0 1 2 3 4"** with 5 tokens
it has to generate:-

- 0 2 3 4
- 0 1 3 4
- 0 1 2 4
- 0 1 4
- 0 2 4
- 0 3 4
- 0 4

I wrote a code that takes num of words in the sentence and then generates all possible sentences which I want.
My Code is

```
public static void TestPattern(int numOfWords) {
    int blankCount=1;
    while(blankCount<numOfWords-1) {
        for(int i=1;i<=numOfWords-blankCount-1;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=numOfWords-1;j++) {
                boolean blankFound=false;
                for(int z=0;z<blankCount;z++) {
                    if(j==i+z) {
                        blankFound=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(blankFound==false) {
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print("_ ");

                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }           
        blankCount++;
    }
}
```

when I called this function **TestPattern(5)**
you can realize that it misses non-consecutive cases such as

- 0 2 4    **"0 __ 2 __ 4 "**

As you see below that I generate sentences with consecutive words "blank out" or "dropped"

```
                for(int z=0;z<blankCount;z++) {
                    if(j==i+z) {
                        blankFound=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(blankFound==false) {
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print("_ ");

                }
```

Also iterate over with blankCount variable in order to generate strings by removing one, two consecutive,..etc words

```
    int blankCount=1;
```

How can I modify my algorithm in order to find these cases?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [I downvoted because it appears that you didn't make any effort to debug this yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: I did. but I can not write an algorithm in order to get misses cases

Comment: Define the algorithm you're trying to implement.  Add to your code (1) meaningful variable names; (2) comments as needed to follow the algorithm; (3) output statements to track the data and control flow.

Comment: If you just need the problem solved (rather than fixing your particular code), do the research: you're trying to generate all combinations of the middle elements, a problem that is treated quite well on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.  "All combinations of array elements" or "all subsets" should get you what you need.

Comment: You don't need so many lines for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for trying. 
I realized a nicer approach to solving this problem.
You can consider every string as a binary number then you iterate over it if you find 0 you have to drop this word.

Then what are the possible values for every string?!
if a number of words in your string is 4 so your possible generated string will be between 2^3+1 and 2^4-1. you can ignore all even numbers between two ranges as it will end with 0 and you should not drop the last word.

As example, **"0 1 2 3"** string has 4 words so it will generate

- 1001 ( 0 _ _ 3 )
- 1011 ( 0 _ 2 3 )
- 1101 ( 0 1 _ 3 )

in my case with 5 words:-

- 10001 (0 4)
- 10011 (0 3 4)
- 10101 (0 2 4)
- 11001 (0 1 4)
- 11011 (0 1 3 4)
- 11101 (0 1 2 4)
- 10111 (0 2 3 4

The code is :

```
public static void TestPatternBits(int numOfWords) {
    int end=1<<numOfWords;
    int start=1<<(numOfWords-1);

    for(int i=start+1;i<end-1;i+=2) {
        int temp=i;
        while(temp>0) {
            if(temp%2==0) {
                System.out.print("0");
            }else {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
            temp/=2;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```